# Stop program from outputting rest of code when invalid number is entered

Tags: python, input, output

I'm wanting to make a code that only outputs one question at a time.

I have an interactive code that allows someone to enter certain numbers within a range i.e; "0-3".

However, there are about 5 questions that prompts the user to enter a number.

So, if someone was to enter for Q1: "4", the output will still show the following questions. However, if this were to happen, I want it to show "Invalid Number! Try Again".

Is there a specific code to stop this from happening?

I have thus far:

```py
if inp == 0:

    out = "Beginner"

elif inp == 1:

    out = "Intermediate"

elif inp == 2:

    out = "Advanced"

else:

    f=1

    if f > 3:

        print('Invalid input!')

        return
```

(rest of code using return when needed)

Answer (score 1):

Then you should use a `while` loop and keep displaying the question if the user didn't select a valid input:

```
def display_question(sentence,
                     choices=['Beginner', 'Intermediate', 'Advanced']):
    again = True

    while again:
        inp = input(sentence).strip()

        # Check if the user entered a digit
        if inp.isdigit():
            user_number = int(inp)

            if user_number >= 0 and user_number < len(choices):
                print("Your choice is {}".format(choices[user_number]))
                return choices[user_number]

        # If the input is not valid, display error message and retry
        print('Invalid input! Try again')
```

```
display_question('Make your choice (0: Beginner, 1: Intermediate, 2: Advanced): ')
```